# Mutually update material switch in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have to swtiches. I want each switch to force the other one to FALSE should they become TRUE. (e.g. if you 'toggle' switch1 (= TRUE), and switch2 = TRUE, then switch2 should be changed to FALSE).

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)


ui <- fluidPage(
  materialSwitch(inputId = "switch1", label = "Switch 1", status = "danger"),
  materialSwitch(inputId = "switch2", label = "Switch 2", status = "danger")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  

  
  observeEvent(input$switch1, {
    #if (is.null(input$switch1)) return(NULL)
    if (input$switch1 == TRUE && input$switch2 == TRUE) {
      updateMaterialSwitch(session = session, "switch2", status = "danger", value = FALSE)
    }
  },
  ignoreInit = TRUE)
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried passing the input to a reactive event, but everytime I trigger switch1 after switch2 has been triggered, the app enters an endless loop. Any suggestions?

The end game would be for condition to work both ways, but for now since it doens't even work in one direction I would appreciate some help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  materialSwitch(inputId = "switch1", label = "Switch 1", status = "danger"),
  materialSwitch(inputId = "switch2", label = "Switch 2", status = "danger")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$switch1, {
    if (input$switch1 == TRUE && input$switch2 == TRUE) {
      updateMaterialSwitch(session = session, "switch2", value = FALSE)
    }
  })
  observeEvent(input$switch2, {
    if (input$switch1 == TRUE && input$switch2 == TRUE) {
      updateMaterialSwitch(session = session, "switch1", value = FALSE)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work fine. Was it actually the status in the update that was causing failure?

Comment: Well thanks a lot again , I was stuck on this all morning!